# How to create virtual (in memory) SD card?

Tags: android, memory

Is it possible in Android create virtual (in memory) SD card?

Comment: use the following link to create virtual sd card in android   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#sdcard

Comment: That's a virutal SD card for the emulator, but it's a disk image file - though I suppose you could place it on a host ramdisk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  At least not on today's phones, which don't really have enough ram to do this.

Also you'd need root or a modified platform in order to create a ramdisk and point the things that should point to the sdcard there instead.

But if you had root, and the ram, the capability is there from the underlying linux (and even already used by android to make small ramdisks for other purposes), you'd just need to set it up right.  This might apply on some non-phone device with more memory than it needs for ordinary operation.